# how to convert "Button b3 = (Button)sender" from c# to ironpython

Tags: .net, silverlight, ironpython

I want to convert C# statement

```
Button b3 = (Button)sender;
```

to ironpython statement

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sender is typed to object (in other words there are no user defined conversion operators) you can just use sender like you would b3 in the C# code.  The **exact** same code would be:

b3 = sender

C# only needs to do this because it wants to statically type objects.  If instead of Button you were casting to an interface for an object where it's explicitly implemented it gets more complicated.

Comment: The C# compiler can insert an implicit or explicit cast to a `Button` in this case, possibly causing an overloaded operator on `sender` to be called. This is behavior you don't get in IronPython.

Comment: That's the reason I qualified this with "there are no user defined conversion operators".  Assuming this is a WinForms or WPF Button, and we're casting from object (both likely), then there are no user defined conversion operators here.  That's because the WinForms and WPF hierarchies don't define the user defined conversion operators and you can't add one for object.

Comment: And if you do want to ensure user defined conversions run you can call clr.Convert.

Answer (score 0):

b3 = sender.Content()